# help in an example.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, krull-dimension

In page 226 of *David Eisenbud*'s book *Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry* there is an example which I need help in some parts of it:

[image]

why $codim I= 1$? why $dim M = dim R = 2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use $x,y,z$ for the variables of $R$. Notice that $(x)(y,z) = (xy,xz)$. If we want to form a chain of prime ideals of $R$ terminating at $I$, then they must all contain $xy$ and $xz$. But this implies that they either contain $x$, or $y$ and $z$. If they contain $x$, then so too does $I$, but this is a contradiction. So they must contain $y,z$. But then clearly, $(y,z)\subseteq (x+1, y,z) = I$ is a maximal chain, so the height is $1$.

$M$ is the set of primes containing $x$. A maximal chain here is $(x)\subseteq(x,y)\subseteq(x,y,z)$ just as in the comments.

Comment: $(y)\subseteq(y,z)\subseteq (x+1, y,z)$. isn't true?

Comment: Dear @uns, are you talking about the chain for $M$? The first prime ideal must contain $(y,z)$ since it cannot contain $x$.

Comment: I.e. $(xy,xz)\nsubseteq (y)$.

Comment: thanks. +1. I mean $(y)\subseteq(y,z)\subseteq (x+1, y,z)=I$. sorry. I am confused. what is M, L and N; exactly?

Comment: Dear @uns, $M$ is the plane defined by $x=0$ (the ideal $(x)$), $L$ is the line defined by $y=z=0$ (the ideal $(y,z)$), and $N$ is the point defined by $x+1=y=z=0$ (the ideal $(x+1,y,z)$).

Comment: The main point is that prime ideals of $R$ correspond to prime ideals of $k[x,y,z]$ which contain the ideal $(x)(y,z) = (xy,xz)$. The ideal $(y)$ does not contain $(xy,xz)$. More directly, $(y)$ cannot be prime in $R$ since for example $xz = 0\in (y)$, but neither $x$ nor $z$ is in $(y)$.